# How to secure Udp?

Tags: c#, performance, security, sockets, udp

I'm working on a server project in C#(.Net). I have a Tcp connection (with SSL). I can secure communication in Tcp. I need to create Udp system for sending datas fast. Now how can I secure Udp? Udp is connection-less, datagram protocol. I think there is a way, thats:

```
> Client connects via Tcp, Server sends a random (16 byte lenght) key to Client via Tcp.
> If client wants to send data via Udp, it replaces the data like this (key[16 byte lengt] + data)
> Server checks incoming data's first 16 byte and if it's true, generates an other random password and sends it client back via Tcp.
> Clients understands new key via incoming Tcp data, and uses the new key.
```

Namely after all success Udp process, server creates an other random key for the client and sends it to client. Client uses key for the Udp authentication.

Yes this is a true way but I wont send new data after Udp process. Because there is a performance issue. Udp must be fast but if you send a data after every success udp process, this can create a lag server-side. I want to make a Udp security with one operation. (only Udp send, no Tcp callback)

If there is no way to do it, I'm going to use that system. Anybody know something about this?

(**NOTE:** I know, asymmetric cryptology is the best way (SSL using) but I can't create my super secure cryptology (like 128-bit) function.)

***EDIT:** Is there a way to use SSL with Udp?*

Comment: You can secure UDP with DTLS. But I'm not aware of a DTLS implementation for .NET. The way you describe to secure UDP is completely insecure, as it provides neither integrity nor confidentiality.

Comment: @dtb There is no way to do it in .Net without 3rd party softwares right? Err, can I use my system(sending Udp key to client after success udp data), is it good way to do it?

Comment: Yes, you need 3rd party software for DTLS. No, your system is not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, use DTLS (Datagram TLS). DTLS is an extension of TLS protocol to support unreliable carriers like UDP (but it doesn't require UDP and can work over piggeon mail, for example).

Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php) product offers components and classes for DTLS in .NET edition (as well as in other editions).